# SqlBulkCopy can not insert all records on the server

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to upload my Excel file with large amounts of data into SQL Server. The code runs perfectly on the local machine, but on the server, it is not pulling all the records as it should.

This is my `web.config` (using IMEX=1)

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'"/>
```

I am using `BulkCopyTimeout` and Batch size. Below is the sample of my code

```
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PLANT", "PLANT");
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SHRPCMINMAX", "SHRPCMINMAX");

sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
sqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;

con.Open();
sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
con.Close();
```

I am not able to figure out that why is it not pulling all the records on the server as it is working perfectly fine on the local.

Comment: Bind your Datatable to a Gridview and then review the data to see if the missing data is actually present in the data table or not..

Comment: What type of server are you using?  Where is the file located?  What type of account are you running the code on the server?  If you are on a IIS server users have limited access to the c: drive on the server and there may be a credential issue.

Comment: @jdweng I am on a IIS server and importing the file from local system C drive.

Comment: @MarkKram everything works fine with the same data file and the same code when I am trying it on the local.

Comment: @jdweng Sometimes I can pull all the data on the server as well but other times it would just crash the server and I have to restart the server every time.

Comment: Do you think it may be a sharing issue of the excel file?  If somebody has the excel file open it may cause the crash.

Comment: @jdweng excel file is just local to the users system, so it can not be opened on another system at the same time. But it works fine for less records on the server as well but when I try to pull a large file of 150k records it will just pull 15k records for that file. So the import is working but not pulling up all the data from the file to the sql server.

Comment: Are there any empty rows (or empty cells in primary key column)?  Somebody has to move the excel files to server which could cause sharing or two people simultaneously doing queries.

Comment: there are no empty rows. But if we say there were that could have caused the problem in the local as well right? Yes sharing the files or simultaneous uploads of the excel file on the server could be the issue over here.

Comment: but if it is a smaller file it would be imported any how its just having problems with the excel files having data larger than 10k rows. @jdweng

Answer (score 0):

Check your datatable before sending it to the BCP process. Make sure it contains everything. The code looks OK, so the only thing that jumps out at me would be the data.

Comment: The data is the same while importing on the local as well. If there was something wrong with the data or datatable then it won't be working on the local as well